# How do I replace a charakter in a string n times, each time with a new charakter of a given list?

Tags: python, for-loop, replace, format

I've got the following string, where I want to replace `A1` with each charakter of the list `befcodes` and than print it:

```
befcodes = ["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","A9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"]
telegram = "$00;02;A1;00000000*49"
```

I'd like to get an output that looks something like this:

```
$00;02;A1;00000000*49
$00;02;A2;00000000*49
$00;02;A3;00000000*49
......
$00;02;19;00000000*49
$00;02;20;00000000*49
```

I tried a few different methods with string formatting and for loops but didn't quite get the hang of it. Can you guys help me out?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `str.replace`

```
befcodes = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", 
            "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"]
telegram = "$00;02;A1;00000000*49"

for code in befcodes:
    print(telegram.replace("A1", code))
```

Giving

```
$00;02;A1;00000000*49
$00;02;A2;00000000*49
$00;02;A3;00000000*49
...
$00;02;18;00000000*49
$00;02;19;00000000*49
$00;02;20;00000000*49
```